# How can I store in a variable certain lines in python?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, debian

I have this code:

```
with open("/etc/network/interfaces", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()
    print content
```

it's working and showing this:

[image]

How can I store in a variable any word and print that word?

Comment: What exactly are you asking exactly - what are you trying to do?

Comment: For example, I want to store the word (lo) in the second line in a variable and then print that variable.

Comment: So some parsing on the file then... just one line in particular or...? This is a bit broad at the moment...

Comment: You want to do it for all the words or only for a given number of words in your file ?

Comment: Only for a given number of word, for example I have: "lo" next to the word "auto" you see it? I want to save the word "lo" in that line in a variable and after that print it. Can you help me?

Comment: If you want to save 'lo' why not `my_var = 'io'` ?  Your question makes no sense.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @joelgoldstick get the exact position of the first "iface" for example and print it.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("/etc/network/interfaces", "r") as file:
for line in file:
    words=line.split(' ')#break the line into a list of words.
    print(words[0],words[1]) #
```

I have not tested it, but gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, I want to store the word (lo) in the second line in a variable and then print that variable.

Use the re module in Python's builtin library:

```
import re

with open("/etc/network/interfaces", "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()

target_word = re.findall("lo()", content[3]) # save the string 'lo' into target word
print ''.join(target_word) # prints: lo
```

If you plan on trying to find more words, just add more words to the regular expression. For example, if you wanted to find the words lo and auto, you would say `re.findall("lo|auto", content)`. If you use this method, I recommend reading the [official documentation on the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Thank you! why prints "lo" four times? and how could I save "lo" into a variable?

Comment: @AlvaroEnrique I could have misunderstood you. Do you want all occurrences of the word `lo`, or do you only want the `lo` by the word auto?

Comment: Yes, only the lo by the word auto

Comment: @AlvaroEnrique got you. gimme a sec to update my answer.